# Is there a way to group same type variable in Angular 2 Typescript component?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

Is there a Java-like way to group same type variables in component?

For example, I have:

```
foo1: string;
foo2: string;
donald3: string;
```

is there a way to do something like this?

```
foo1, foo2, donald3: string;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such syntax. You gotta have to include the type for each variable.